# remove empty lines on a column mysql

Tags: mysql

I removed some text from my columns with

1. `UPDATE mytable SET format = REPLACE(format, 'company', '');`
   but it seems that the lines are not deleted as you can see on the screenshot

I tried

2. `delete from mytable where format='' OR format IS NULL`

but nothing

is there a way to remove these empty lines.
thanks

[column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWidy.png)

Comment: Multi-line content of the column is one solid value. You cannot remove the line from the value by this way. Use UPDATE and REGEXP_REPLACE() which replaces 2 or more adjacent linebreaks with one linebreak.

Comment: Well as per your picture ___(PS Please dont show us pictures of anything)___ You do not have any rows with a `format` column that is NULL or an empty string i.e. `''` All you did was remove the word `company` from any/all the rows that may have contained it. So now you have no way to identify the rows you want to Delete

Answer (score 4):

Here's a demo: I create some string with a leading blank line, and a couple of extra blank lines in the middle.

```
mysql> set @string = '
    '> abc
    '> 
    '> 
    '> def';
```

I can remove the blank lines in the middle, but it doesn't remove the initial single blank line.

```
mysql> select regexp_replace(@string, '\n\n', '') as string;
+----------+
| string   |
+----------+
| 
abc
def |
+----------+
```

And vice-versa:

```
mysql> select regexp_replace(@string, '^\n', '') as string;
+-----------+
| string    |
+-----------+
| abc


def |
+-----------+
```

But I can pass the result of one as the input to the other, and achieve both substitutions:

```
mysql> select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(@string, '\n\n', ''), '^\n', '') as string;
+---------+
| string  |
+---------+
| abc
def |
+---------+
```

Note that [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) requires MySQL 8.0. If you are still using MySQL 5.x, then you need to upgrade.

Comment: I got the distinct feeling the OP wanted to delete the rows that had the text `company` in the `format` column, but having used `replace()` has removed that text whereever it may have existed, but is still wanting to delete the rows that previously had it in. Of course I could be barking up the wrong tree, it might not be the first time for that :)

Comment: `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(@val, '(^|\n)\n+', '$1')` is enough.

Comment: Although now I am not so sure :)

Comment: Thanks fo your help guys. But Like @RiggsFolly I just wanted to deleted the blank likes under "firstname lastname). these 2 lines because I removed 'company' and 'vat_number' with --UPDATE mps_address_format SET format = REPLACE(format, 'vat_number', '')-- and --UPDATE mps_address_format SET format = REPLACE(format, 'company', '')--. isn't there a simple way to delete these2 blank lines . thanks again

Comment: Ok, so it was I that was barking up the wrong tree, so the suggestions that Bill made are what you need to be looking at

Comment: Do you know of any other programming language that could do this more simply?